# Width of GroupView in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a problem with setting width of TextView in ExpandableListView in GroupView. This ExpandableListView is placed in sliding menu.
When menu is slide first time, GroupView looks like this:
[image]

But when we tap on some option it looks like this:

[image]

And this is proper view, which I like to be every time, not only when we tap on some group options. How can I fix this bug?

Here is my source code:

activity_main.xml

```
  <ExpandableListView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:divider="@color/blue"
        android:childDivider="@color/blue"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        />
```

expandable_list_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@drawable/expandable_list_item_background"
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_text_selector"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

expandable_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_text_selector"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainLayout.java (method where slide menu width is setting)

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    mainLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    menuRightMargin = mainLayoutWidth * 20 / 100;
}
```